# Removing a 'dead' thing from an array

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk, null

I'm new to Corona. I'm working on a simple TD game. I have walls (barricades) that the player can drag out onto the battlefield and then the enemy swarm towards a goal-destination. If they encounter a barricade, they take health off it until it hits zero then the barricade disappears.

The code I have for the barricades being killed and removed is as follows:

```
if (barricadeCount == 0) then
    print ("No barricades left")
else
    for i = 1, totalBarricades do       
            if (barricade[i].isAttacked == true) and (barricade[i].health == 0) then 
                print ("REMOOOOOVING BARRICADE", i)
                local deadBarricade = table.remove(barricade,i)
                deadBarricade:removeSelf()
                deadBarricade = nil
                totalBarricades = totalBarricades - 1 --one less in the 'total'!
            end
            if (barricade[i].isAttacked == true) and (barricade[i].health > 0) then
                barricade[i].health = barricade[i].health - 10
                --and change graphic to show damage
                print ("barricade",i,"health is now",barricade[i].health)
            end
    end
totalBarricades = totalBarricades - 1
```

Now the problem I have is that when the first barricade 'dies', I get a crash and

> 'attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

I suspect it has something to do with the contents of the barricade array renumbering itself but I just can't figure it out. I'd be so incredibly grateful if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: If an object dies you remove it from the array, but you then immediately access the same barricade[i] for check health - If the entry is removed is the last entry, you will access a nil at the end. I would have do: 1) Subtract health  2) if health <= 0 then die and remove.

Answer (score 0):

Dont remove it in the table, just let it be. Lua tables are designed to handle indefinite values as long as your device can carry the load. just do `deadBarricade:removeSelf()` to clear some memory. I expect some lag time when you shift elements from table everytime a barricade is removed. What if lots of barricade is removed at the same time? I dont know what error it might end up but I'm anticipating it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurs when total barricade count goes to zero and it tries to run a check on alive barricades in the following code.

> if (barricade[i].isAttacked == true) and (barricade[i].health > 0) then

The table gets out of index and the error pops up. 
You can add in an additional check to make sure you are not referring to a nil object.

```
if (barricade[i] and barricade[i].isAttacked == true) and (barricade[i] and barricade[i].health > 0) then
```